# how to allow user sign up in gitlab but restrict their email to specific domain?

Tags: gitlab

I can enable user sign up by edit `config/gitlab.yaml`

```
## Users management
signup_enabled: true          # default: false
```

I want to restrict user email to domain mycompany.com when signuped so that only people in my company can create a gitlab account. such as:

```
tom@mycompany.com   # ok to sign up
jerry@mycompany.com # ok to sign up

abc@example.com # disallow to sign up
```

how to configure it in gitlab?

Comment: A regexp would do it, if gitlab allows it in the config file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

2013: That was recently requested ([issue](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4413) 4413), but <del>not yet implemented</del>.

Implemented in 2016 ([Merge Request 598](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/598), GitLab 7.11, May 2015) in the Admin Area:

[image: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/uploads/b312046aae03971f37f4247382971fc6/image.png]

---

Original answer (2013):

That would be similar to the Atlassian Confluence setting:

[image: Confluance setting]

So pull requests are welcome.

**[edit]**
Feature request was moved [here](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/4118466-ability-to-register-only-from-ceratain-domains).

Answer (score 0):

This was implemented, you can find the white/black list in the admin under Settings.